# Прокомментировать и пропустить vs прокомментировать и тревогнуть?

Tags: обсуждение

Листая очередь на проверку низкокачественных вопросов, встречаю вопросы, которые явно низкокачественные и требуют некоторой работы автора по улучшению.

[Конкретный пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609862/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-gui) даю скриншотом, т.к. не знаю, проделает ли автор работу, которую просят или нет (возможно, вопрос изменится):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня как у проверяющего, какая должна быть наиболее оптимальная стратегия?

Вижу два варианта:

1. Нажать тревогу и тем самым указать, что сообщение **на текущий момент проверки** действительно низкого качества. В случае, если автор исправит сообщение и другие проверяющие дадут ответ "выглядит нормально" - я ухудшаю свою статистку проверяющего, как зря тревогающий.
2. Подписать комментарий с рекомендацией автору дополнить свой вопрос и не тревогать. Худшее, что может быть - это в случае если автор не исправит пост и все проверяющие дадут ответ "выглядит нормально" - ну останется висеть не очень хорошего качества вопрос, собственно в конкретном случае уже и ответ есть - такой же бла-бла-бла, как и сам вопрос "подскажите, на чём писать GUi" - "GUI можно писать на чём угодно".

Answer (score 4):

Конкретно этот пример я бы сразу слал в печку и не беспокоился. Но я думаю, что вы пришли сюда за общим алгоритмом.

---

#### Общий алгоритм

У меня такой алгоритм:

1. Можно ли вообще этот вопрос потенциально сделать полезным?
2. Если да, то я нажимаю "Пропустить" и оставляю комментарий для автора, о том как можно было бы улучшить данный вопрос. Если нет реакции в течение 1-2ч к моему комментарию, то я помечаю вопрос "Тревогой".
3. Если нет, то просто нажимаю "Тревогу".
4. Если сомневаюсь, то зависит от моей компетенции и самого вопроса (насколько он может быть полезен). Могу выбрать как и вариант 2, так и вариант 3.

---

#### Нарушение правил ради очень полезных ответов

Иногда я знаю, что вопрос безнадёжно "слишком общий" и поэтому неформат ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/606708/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-cunity)), но вижу, что очень полезен. Он может быть даже дубликат, как и приведённый пример. Но я не буду его помечать тревогой, потому что он нуждается в ответах. Я не собираюсь содействовать закрытию таких вопросов.

На enSO подобные вопросы (закрытые, но очень полезные) помогают минимум сотням тысяч людей (и очень жалко что их закрывают, потому что эти вопросы тоже нуждаются в новых ответах), несмотря на неформат. Я думаю каждый такие вопросы видел неоднократно. И ради таких вопросов, я бы правило ("невозможно дать объективно верный ответ") нарушал.

Answer (score 1):

Конечная задача проекта – собрать базу многократно используемых решений. В этом случае, по большому счету, полноценная пара вопрос–ответ намного важнее получения ответа автором вопроса (это так, потому что вашим ответом в будущем воспользуются многие коллеги, пришедшие из поиска, а не только автор вопроса).

Если вы видите не до конца однозначно сформулированный вопрос, следует запросить у автора уточнений, а, при необходимости, проголосовать против или даже за закрытие вопроса. Если вы примерно догадываетесь о чем идет речь в вопросе, можно на свой страх и риск самостоятельно внести изменения в вопрос и опубликовать на него ответ (пример: [Как получить список процессов запущенных пользователем с фильтром по имени?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/608591/6)). В этом случае, в базе знаний остается заметка «вопрос–ответ» *хорошего качества*, что само по себе коррелирует с миссией проекта, а автор вопроса, с какой-то вероятностью, получит нужный ему ответ. Если на самом деле вопрос был в другом, автор всегда может задать новый вопрос, содержащий более точную формулировку.

На абстрактном уровне можно рассматривать вопрос как ключ к хранящемся в памяти знаниям. Если вы хорошо понимаете как его исправить «ключ» так, чтобы по нему можно было найти нужные у вас знания, пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь внести изменения в вопрос!